# Hibernate/JPA delete not catching Exception on JTA Persistence Unit without em.flush()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, exception

We are migrating our PersistenceUnit from `RESOURCE_LOCAL` to `JTA`. In the remove cases like below, the Exception it's not raised without an em.flush() after the em.remove().

```
 public boolean delete(T t) {
    try {
        em.remove(em.contains(t) ? t : em.merge(t));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Debugging the code in NetBeans, the system enter the `return true` and THEN do the database transaction.
This behavior it's not wrong? Using `em.flush()` solve the problem but it's the right approach? Cause in `RESOURCE_LOCAL` we didn't use and works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityManager delays the database operations because it *might* be able to process them more efficiently. For instance if you deleted two entities it would be able to remove them with a single DELETE statement.

If your application needs the delete to happen immediately, calling `flush()` is probably fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guillaume, what we couldn't understand is why this situation didn't occur in the `RESOURCE_LOCAL` PersistenceUnit. Now thinking about the problem, might be the way GlassFish handle the operation inside the PersistenceContext.

Comment: The JPA spec does not go into details for all cases, so the providers can implement things differently